# Ember.js: Ember.Select valueBinding and lazy loading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a view with disabled selector that should be set to the value from ember-data as soon as the model is loaded.

```
LocationSelectView: Ember.Select.extend({
    prompt: "Choose location",
    contentBinding: 'controller.locations',
    optionValuePath: 'content.id',
    optionLabelPath: 'content.title',
    valueBinding: 'controller.content.location_id'
})
```

and the view is disabled in template

```
{{view view.LocationSelectView disabled="true"}}
```

everything is working as expected as long as the locations were already loaded to the store,
if they are not loaded, the content is binding as expected (I can verify that by enabling the selector), but the selected value stays at the "prompt".

I worked around this by pre-loading the locations data in the controller's init, but I really don't like this solution.

how can I fix this ? is it a bug ?

Comment: I know there was bug around this, perhaps this one is fixed in master.  Could you try with master (if not already the case). If it does not work, it would be great if you can file an issue in ember.js github, and link a jsfiddle

Comment: I created a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bsphere/H8BUf/ I'm not sure this is a bug, but I also don't know how to achieve required behavior. the selected value is loaded before the Ember.Select content. but that value is erased once Ember.Select initializes because of the binding

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mentioned here:  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1333

My solution was to add an observer to the view like this:

```
preselect: function () {
  var item = this.get('items.firstObject');
  this.set('currentItem', item);
}.observes('items.@each')
```

That presumes using selectionBinding (which I prefer) instead of valueBinding

Answer (score 0):

I developed a workaround for this problem. Look at the following code:

```
App.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
placeholder: '',
allowClear: false,

contentChanged: function() {
    if (this.get('value') === undefined && this.get('_iv') != undefined) {
        var v = this.get('_iv');
        var o = this.get('content').findProperty('id', v);

        if (o) {
            this.set('value', v);
        }
    }
}.observes('content.@each'),

init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('_iv', this.get('value'));
},
```

...

I hope it helps